# Does anyone know of a good host for LaTeX software development? - SourceForge has a new owner and installers might get bundled up with adware

Tags: discussion, community, package-authors

This is a question because of something I stumbled over on reddit. I wanted to "alert" the community to the issue which is, as far as I understood it: software from SourceForge might only be available with adware or malware in the future, it's already the case for Filezilla. It is depicted in its full glory on [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/1kxuul/beware_of_sourceforge_downloads_new_owner_is/). Not that I mean to impose on everyone to read the thread of course! I just that I think it's a sign of the times (again, sort of, adware did vanish in the last couple of years imho) and it's worth mentioning on here, as some developers in the LaTeX community host their project on SourceForge.

In the case of [FileZilla](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=30240), the primary download option on its homepage links to SourceForge. So there are still alternative downloads available. But the problem is that—although I have not tested it myself—apparently the installer from SourceForge does not work when unchecking the additional software ([source](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=30240&sid=d1aacf1c6b96a63aa9fa85ca670dfcd1&start=15#p113915)) (not that I would advice anyone to 
use that installer anyway):

> The SourceForge installer won't work for me on Windows 8 x64. when I click on the decline button for the sponsored product the installer quits without displaying any error message. I have downloaded it 3 times just in case, each time Windows verifies it as being digitally signed and the same issue happens.

Comment: can we `uncheck` the adware/malware to skip them during installation ? may be change Q title to "How to stop installing adware and malware:in view of LaTeX sphere  projects at sourceforge(packaged with adware etc..)" to bring in some ideas or "how to stop adware while installing TeX related software" on tex.sx also will do

Comment: You made good alert news. If you can take an effort to improve Q based on my above comments into a good focussed Question then it becomes interesting and benefit many people due to its serious issue involved.

Comment: I amended the op. Took me a while since I am incredibly busy at the moment so I just got around to it. :)

Comment: may be `Build from source` is good option if source tar ball is available to avoid them